# Mapping Nested Object properties into one ViewModel with EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Hey there, I am new to MVC3 and EF 4.1 and am trying to create a structure where my ViewModel contains a flattened representation of a nested set of objects. I am wondering if EF 4.1 handles this scenario. I've done some reading and can't even find the terminology to use for a search. Essentially what I would like to do is create a ViewModel based on parts of different domain Models. so something like this is my nested set of models and at the bottom is my desired ViewModel:

```
class ModelA
    property one
    property two
    property three

class ModelB
    property eh
    property be
    property cee
    property ModelC modC

class ModelC
    property une
    property deux
    property trois
    property ModelD modD

class ModelD
    property x
    property y
    property z


class ShowStuffViewModel
    property one
    property two
    property be
    property trois
    property y
    property z
```

I keep thinking that I have the concept wrong but ultimately I'd like to be able to map the property automatically down through the table nesting from my ViewModel just by naming convention regardless of what level the property lives at. I figure this way I don't have to carry around large set of objects when I only need a few data points from each. I also would like to make a LINQ call to populate the ViewModel Properties by querying on the two base models ModelA and ModelB and then assign the values directly to the ViewModel.

Please pardon the newb details here as I just beginning my OOP MVC etc journey and any help or guidance is much appreciated!

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is called projection. I don't understand how `ModelA` is related to other models so I will skip it in example but for rest you can simply create this query:

```
var query = from b in context.ModelBs
            // some join for ModelA here? 
            // Models must be related if you want to load them with single query
            select new ShowStuffViewModel
                {
                    be = b.be,
                    trois = b.ModelC.trois,
                    y = b.ModelC.ModelD.y, 
                    z = b.ModelC.ModelD.z 
                };
```